# Экранирование обратного слеша в строке JS

Tags: javascript, c#, строки, символы, экранирование

Как можно разом экранировать все обратные слеши в строке?

На C# это делается очень просто:

```cs
String Path = @"C:\Users\User\Desktop\file.txt";
```

Одним символом @ экранируются все обратные слеши.
Есть ли подобное в JS?
Не писать же постоянно "\\" ...

Comment: Нет. Писать постоянно. Ну или свалить с винды на нормальну систему, там нормальные слеши. А вообще-то нода вполне понимает в винде пути с обычным слешом. `c:/users/desktop/...`

Comment: @AlexeyTen причем здесь винда, если вопрос по JS? Или в вашей ОС javascript как то по другому работает?

Comment: @tym32167 в других системах такой проблемы просто не существует. Тут ничего не нужно экранировать `/home/alexeyten/file.txt`

Comment: @AlexeyTen я так понял, вопрос про экранирование слешей вцелом, а не только про пути к файлам и папкам. Хотя это автору лучше знать. К тому же никто не будет менять ОС из за проблем с экранированием в JS

Comment: @AlexeyTen, так-то windows понимает оба варианта